# Can't install with "pkg" the packages for ImageMagick on OpenIndiana (OpenSolaris 11)

Tags: unix, solaris, opensolaris, openindiana

Anytime I try to install one of the ImageMagick packages, primary pkg:/image/imagemagick, I get the following (repeated) error:

> pkg install: The following packages all deliver file actions to
>   usr/include/webp/encode.h:
>
> pkg://openindiana.org/library/libwebp@0.4.0,5.11-2016.0.0.0:20160730T003751Z
>   pkg://sfe/image/library/libwebp@0.2.1,5.11-0.151.1.8:20130901T155736Z
>
> These packages may not be installed together. Any non-conflicting set
>   may be, or the packages must be corrected before they can be
>   installed.
>
> The following packages all deliver file actions to
>   usr/share/man/man1/dwebp.1:
>
> pkg://openindiana.org/library/libwebp@0.4.0,5.11-2016.0.0.0:20160730T003751Z
>   pkg://sfe/image/library/libwebp@0.2.1,5.11-0.151.1.8:20130901T155736Z
>
> These packages may not be installed together. Any non-conflicting set
>   may be, or the packages must be corrected before they can be
>   installed.
>
> The following packages all deliver file actions to
>   usr/lib/amd64/pkgconfig/libwebp.pc:
>
> pkg://openindiana.org/library/libwebp@0.4.0,5.11-2016.0.0.0:20160730T003751Z
>   pkg://sfe/image/library/libwebp@0.2.1,5.11-0.151.1.8:20130901T155736Z
>
> These packages may not be installed together. Any non-conflicting set
>   may be, or the packages must be corrected before they can be
>   installed.
>
> The following packages all deliver file actions to usr/bin/dwebp:
>
> pkg://openindiana.org/library/libwebp@0.4.0,5.11-2016.0.0.0:20160730T003751Z
>   pkg://sfe/image/library/libwebp@0.2.1,5.11-0.151.1.8:20130901T155736Z
>
> These packages may not be installed together. Any non-conflicting set
>   may be, or the packages must be corrected before they can be
>   installed.
>
> The following packages all deliver file actions to
>   usr/include/webp/decode.h:
>
> pkg://openindiana.org/library/libwebp@0.4.0,5.11-2016.0.0.0:20160730T003751Z
>   pkg://sfe/image/library/libwebp@0.2.1,5.11-0.151.1.8:20130901T155736Z
>
> These packages may not be installed together. Any non-conflicting set
>   may be, or the packages must be corrected before they can be
>   installed.
>
> The following packages all deliver file actions to
>   usr/include/webp/types.h:
>
> pkg://sfe/image/library/libwebp@0.2.1,5.11-0.151.1.8:20130901T155736Z 
>   pkg://openindiana.org/library/libwebp@0.4.0,5.11-2016.0.0.0:20160730T003751Z
>
> These packages may not be installed together. Any non-conflicting set
>   may be, or the packages must be corrected before they can be
>   installed.
>
> The requested change to the system attempts to install multiple
>   actions for link 'usr/lib/libwebp.so' with conflicting attributes:
>
> ```
> 1 package delivers 'link path=usr/lib/libwebp.so target=libwebp.so.4.0.1':
>     pkg://sfe/image/library/libwebp@0.2.1,5.11-0.151.1.8:20130901T155736Z
> 1 package delivers 'link path=usr/lib/libwebp.so target=libwebp.so.5.0.0':
>     pkg://openindiana.org/library/libwebp@0.4.0,5.11-2016.0.0.0:20160730T003751Z
> ```
>
> These packages may not be installed together.  Any non-conflicting set
>   may be, or the packages must be corrected before they can be
>   installed.
>
> The following packages all deliver file actions to
>   usr/lib/pkgconfig/libwebp.pc:
>
> pkg://sfe/image/library/libwebp@0.2.1,5.11-0.151.1.8:20130901T155736Z 
>   pkg://openindiana.org/library/libwebp@0.4.0,5.11-2016.0.0.0:20160730T003751Z
>
> These packages may not be installed together. Any non-conflicting set
>   may be, or the packages must be corrected before they can be
>   installed.
>
> The following packages all deliver file actions to
>   usr/share/man/man1/cwebp.1:
>
> pkg://openindiana.org/library/libwebp@0.4.0,5.11-2016.0.0.0:20160730T003751Z
>   pkg://sfe/image/library/libwebp@0.2.1,5.11-0.151.1.8:20130901T155736Z
>
> These packages may not be installed together. Any non-conflicting set
>   may be, or the packages must be corrected before they can be
>   installed.
>
> The requested change to the system attempts to install multiple
>   actions for link 'usr/lib/amd64/libwebp.so' with conflicting
>   attributes:
>
> ```
> 1 package delivers 'link path=usr/lib/amd64/libwebp.so target=libwebp.so.4.0.1':
>     pkg://sfe/image/library/libwebp@0.2.1,5.11-0.151.1.8:20130901T155736Z
> 1 package delivers 'link path=usr/lib/amd64/libwebp.so target=libwebp.so.5.0.0':
>     pkg://openindiana.org/library/libwebp@0.4.0,5.11-2016.0.0.0:20160730T003751Z
> ```
>
> These packages may not be installed together.  Any non-conflicting set
>   may be, or the packages must be corrected before they can be
>   installed.
>
> The following packages all deliver file actions to usr/bin/cwebp:
>
> pkg://openindiana.org/library/libwebp@0.4.0,5.11-2016.0.0.0:20160730T003751Z
>   pkg://sfe/image/library/libwebp@0.2.1,5.11-0.151.1.8:20130901T155736Z
>
> These packages may not be installed together. Any non-conflicting set
>   may be, or the packages must be corrected before they can be
>   installed.

I see there are two different versions to which it's referring, and I assume that conflict is why it cannot install. However, I have successfully installed a 'libwebp' package:

image/library/libwebp (sfe)                       0.2.1-0.151.1.8            i--

Yet, I still do not know how to get ImageMagic to install. Is there some way to fix this bug? The error output is not descriptive, and it repeats the same error over and over again for each file it 'deliver file actions' for. It saying that 'any non-conflicting set may be, or the packages must be corrected before they can be installed' is not helpful. Maybe someone here is.

Can anyone shed some light on what I must do to get this package to install?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logs look like you've set the IPS publisher to the currently not maintained *old* IPS repository on the OpenIndiana site.
So there is no recommendation possible to get the old packages install propperly on a new version of OpenIndiana.

You should consider not using that IPS repository, as there are no updates to it (at least for quite some longer time).

To see which packages are already installed from there and should be removed, run the command: 
pkg list | grep '(sfe)'

All those package names displayed should be removed.

A currently maintend repository of IPS packages from the "sfe" project is hosted here: http://sfe.opencsw.org or watch the openindiana website for possible other choices.
You can then install the packages in a fresh copy.